# Better to use object method during initialization or after, if you only have one method?

Tags: java, performance, class, runtime

This question is bound to scream poor programming practice, however, I'm curious if there is any performance risk involved here.

Imagine you have a class that only has one method attached (excluding the constructor) to it, for simplicity sake we'll say:

```
public class TestClass{

public TestClass(){

    // Set values or whatever you want in the constructor

}
public String printString(){

    System.out.println("print");
}
}
```

Now considering there is only one method, obviously anytime you use the class you'll probably want to call the method `printString`. So are there any negatives (besides sanity) to putting a call to `printString` in the constructor? Rather than doing `testClass test = new testClass()` then making a call `test.printString()`?

Again, this question is about performance - not programming practice.

Comment: You can put printString in enum and use it everywhere

Comment: Please use upper case letters at the beginning of your class names. java developers get fever seeing a lowercase letter at the beginning of a class name.

Comment: @amit Yeah, yeah. I know. Writing by hand real quick I missed it. Fixed it for ya ;)

Comment: I don't see a difference in performance if you are ALWAYS going to call the printString() method directly after initiating the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is use Enum

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TestEnum;
    public String printString() {
        System.out.println("print");
        return null;
    }
}
```

There will not be much difference in performance point of view but from coding point of view you will have no need to create object every time. Also you can have static utility class as enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `printString` into an enum Utility class or Singleton like

```
public enum TestClass {;
    public static void printString(){
        System.out.println("print");
    }
}
```

However, from a performance point of view, creating a new object each time is very small compared to the cost of writing a line to the console.  The different is notional.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no performance difference** in opinion as compiler has same statements to compile (whether you put the statement in calling class or in constructor) and JVM has exact statements to execute.